# Windows System Reserved Partition mounting in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, system

Guys I've installed windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and both are working good.... the only issue i have is that whenever i boot into Ubuntu...at booting it says...

The disk drive for /windows is not ready yet or not present.
continue to wait ,or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.

After pressing S it boots n works great....but it shows the windows system reserved partition and if i click on it....it mounts...

what i want to do is get rid to that annoying message and hide my windows system reserved partition.

I know it has to do something with fstab but i'm new to Ubuntu so don't want to go messing about things..

THANKS for your help in advance
This is my fstab...

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=8e5b0c69-2c42-4e11-9991-73da7a7aae3c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=f074d97f-2309-44e7-a397-25a5f7e98e3b /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=FECA-7D83  /windows        vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0ad1446c-5d05-490a-9aea-e6dbf0ac2019 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are using wubi.

You can edit /etc/fstab and comment out the entry for the problematic partition.

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/fstab

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add a # in front of the line

```
# UUID=FECA-7D83 /windows vfat utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0 1
```

and add the line:

```
UUID=7C7C735D7C7310DE /mnt/SysRes ntfs defaults,noauto 0 0
```

If you wish your windows partition to be mounted, identify it with blkid

```
sudo blkid
```

And update the UUID in `/etc/fstab`

Save your changes to `/etc/fstab`

For additional information see [Ubuntu wiki fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Comment: ok that got rid of message at sartup but system reserved partion is still there...

Comment: ADDING UUID=7C7C735D7C7310DE /mnt/SysRes ntfs defaults,noauto 0 0 to fstab solved my prob...system reseverd is not shown in ubuntu anymore..